# JBoss Seam: component installed in JNDI, access of component says Not Bound

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, seam

My SFSB Seam component is bound to JNDI on deployment, as evidenced by this log message:

```
Component: example, scope: CONVERSATION, type: STATEFUL_SESSION_BEAN,
class:com.purecharger.action.ExampleAction, JNDI: purecharger/ExampleAction/local
```

My interface:

```
@Local
public interface Example {    
    public List<String> getExample();
    public void destroy();
}
```

and my implementation:

```
@Stateful
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@Name("example")
@Restrict("#{identity.loggedIn}")
public class ExampleAction implements Example, Serializable {

    ....
}
```

However, when I access the `voting` component in an xhtml page like, I get the following error:

```
javax.el.ELException: /home.xhtml: Could not instantiate Seam component: example
....
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ExampleAction not bound
```

If Seam was smart enough to install my component using the JNDI pattern in components.xml (`purecharger/#{ejbName}/local`), why does it not also apply the pattern when looking up components?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
Looking at the JNDIView in JBoss, the name `purecharger/ExampleAction/local` is not bound anywhere. So I guess my question now becomes, why is Seam not adding this SFSB to JNDI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is Seam not adding this SFSB to JNDI ?

Well,

As shown in your question, i think you have a ear application, because of its JNDI global address

```
purecharger/ExampleAction/local
```

which is mapped according to

```
<EAR_APPLICATION>/<STATEFUL_BEAN>/local
```

When you deploy a single EJB module, its JNDI global address in JBoss looks like

```
<STATEFUL_BEAN>/local
```

Bacause you have a ear application, **each EJB module should be declared in application.xml** (The file that describes your ear) as follows

So your ear app looks like

```
pureCharger.ear

    META-INF
        application.xml
    pureCharger-ejb.jar
    pureCharger-war.war
    jboss-seam.jar
    lib
        // libraries shared by your modules goes here
```

And your application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application version="5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd">
    <display-name>pureCharger</display-name>
    <module>
        <ejb>pureCharger-ejb.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <ejb>jboss-seam.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>pureCharger-war.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>pureCharger</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

Notice jboss-seam.jar is a EJB module, so it should also be declared in application.xml file

If possible, use Seam-gen to generate your project. It takes care includes all libraries needed by your project and can be opened without restriction in NetBeans, for instance.

regards,

Comment: Thanks Arthur, this was the problem. Not only did I not declare my EJB-containing jar in application.xml, I was also attempting to have it live in war/WEB-INF/lib, which is not correct (at least until v3.1 of the EJB spec).